# Update table with select expression returning multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am trying to insert value from one column of table into another with slight transformation.

Following query throws me out an error

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

```
update faults_analysis
    set datekey = (select cast(convert(varchar(10),faultstarttime,112) as int) from FAULTS_ANALYSIS )
```

how can I insert multiple values without using cursors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the required reputation to comment on this so I cannot be 100% I am understanding you correctly.

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to update a column in the same table with a transformed value from another column in that table?

Below should be what you require, however please be careful as there is no where clause it assumes you want to update the whole table.

```
    update faults_analysis
       set datekey =  cast(convert(varchar(10),FA.faultstarttime,112) as int)
    from FAULTS_ANALYSIS FA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE faults_analysis
       set datekey =  cast(convert(varchar(10),faultstarttime,112) as int)
```

No need to add **from clause** "from FAULTS_ANALYSIS FA"